# How can I extract values where there are repeated values of fields?

Tags: sql, pgadmin

From the following table,

```
userId passageId score
1      1         2
1      2         3
1      1         4
2      1         3
2      3         3
2      3         4
```

is it possible to extract the scores as shown below when the first two values of passageId are identical for each value of userId.

```
userId passageId score_1 score_2 
1      1         2          4
2      3         3          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8d20328d30de13a39120edf546a28c79)

```
SELECT 
   userId,
   passageId,
   min(score) as score_1,
   max(score) as score_2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY    
   userId,
   passageId
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2;
```

Comment: Is there a way to list successive scores rather than only min and max? For example, how could I list 3 scores for a given userId and passageId?

Comment: Try STRING_AGG for MSSQL or PostgreSQL, and GROUP_CONCAT for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like min and max:

```
select userid, passageid, min(score), max(score)
from t
group by userid, passageid
having count(*) > 1;
```